# Lightweight alternative to base64

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm making a html mosaic creating app, and I use base64 to embed the pictures, and since everything is coded in JS, exporting a mosaic full of pics creates memory leaks in the browser.

How the app works :

- It uses jquery to append content into the mosaic
- Uses base64 to embed pictures
- Exporting exports a single html file with the mosaic in it (and base64 pic)

I was wondering if there was a good lightweight alternative to base64 to embed pictures in on html file. Note that I would like to avoid providing a zip file with the html mosaic + the pictures unless it's the only solution to avoid memory leaks. I would also avoid uploading pictures to a server since it should be offline friendly.

Update : Removed app demo (down)

Comment: You could render the images onto canvas and let users download the canvas as PNG (which is natively supported by browser)

Comment: I'd also stick with the canvas approach. Where, and in which format do your images come from?

Comment: @MightyPork Well, I'm also allowing HTML and text in the mosaics. Plus, I want to make HTML export possible.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Well, the images are uploaded using <input type="file">

Comment: @MightyPork Just wanted to notify you as I added a demo, so you can see how the app works.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat See previous comment :)

Comment: It works fine for me, no freeze. Somehow I fail to see what it'd be good for, but it seems to be ok.

Comment: Even with the canvas' toDataUrl() you'd only get a base64 String so I would not know a method to do this more performant way, except doing base encoding on the server and returning the strings.

Comment: @MightyPork Try putting loads of pictures, then exporting the mosaic (the save button). It freezes and even crashes sometimes.